# Removing the last special character

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I would like to remove the last "/" (special character) from a data-frame column.

For example there are 2 entries

```
1. "/mobile_phones" and 
2. "/mobile_phones/".
```

The text can have multiple '/' in middle for example:
`"/accessories-bandanas_and_headbands/womens/"` .

I would just like to remove rightmost '/' .

I tried the following gsub query

```
ga.data$landingPagePath <- gsub('^\\/&', '', ga.data$landingPagePath)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a simple regex. Note that you don't need to escape the '/', it's not a special character.

```
x <- c("/mobile_phones", "/mobile_phones/", "/accessories-bandanas_and_headbands/womens/")
sub("/\\s*$", "", x)
#[1] "/mobile_phones"                            
#[2] "/mobile_phones"                            
#[3] "/accessories-bandanas_and_headbands/womens"
```

Note also that since it is only one character to be removed, `sub` will do the job, `gsub` should be reserved for when there are multiple occurences of the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are only interested in the last `/` then you would invoke the `$` which indicates that the string ends after the symbol `/`. Also you don't need to use `gsub`. You can use `sub` since you are only replacing one thing in every line

```
vec=c("/mobile_phones",
  "/mobile_phones/",
  "/accessories-bandanas_and_headbands/womens/")

sub("/$","",vec)
[1] "/mobile_phones"                             "/mobile_phones"                            
[3] "/accessories-bandanas_and_headbands/womens"
```

Comment: Someone doesn't like you?

Comment: @RuiBarradas hahaha its okay.. well I just wanted to know the reason for the downvote. But since there is none, its okay